# Converting string with time to minutes

Tags: android, time, type-conversion

I am working on an Android app that gets a time (duration) value as string.

For example, the app can get a value like: 6 hours 43 mins

or a value like: 15 mins

I am looking for a way to convert this strings to an integer value in minutes.

I have tried using this function, but I can´t extract the needed values:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

**Edit:**

it could be possible a result like 6 hours, the only known condition is that minutes are always rounded to an integer, the minimum value is 1 min

Comment: does your string always contain minutes? or is a string like "6 hours" also possible? can it contain seconds? please add some more information about how the string can look

Comment: Please, provide the pattern that are possible ... Using a regex to match every numeric value is probably the easier (don't need to replace to extract the value)

Comment: @Katharina, it depends, but it could be possible a result like 6 hours, the only known condition is that minutes are always rounded to a integer, the minimum value is 1 min

Comment: So the string could also look like this: "1 year 5 months 2 weeks 3 days 2 hours 5 minutes"?
as @AxelH said - please provide all possible patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either String split() or Pattern Matcher, as earlier answers suggest, will work. I'm not sure which will be more efficient though, but it's probably irrelevant in this case. My version:

```
String timeStr = "2 hours 15 mins";
String[] parts = timeStr.split(" ");

int totalMins = 0;
for(int i=1; i< parts.length; i+=2) {
    // Add checking for "days", etc., if necessary.
    if(parts[i].equals("hours")) {
        int h = Integer.parseInt(parts[i-1]);
        totalMins += 60 * h;
    } else if(parts[i].equals("mins")) {
        int m = Integer.parseInt(parts[i-1]);
        totalMins += m;
    }
}

System.out.println("totalMins = " + totalMins);
>> totalMins = 135
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a Regex to get each couple numeric/time_unit. You can easily parse that with :

```
(\\d+) (\\w+)
```

- Group 1 : numeric value
- Group 2 : time unit

  (note that I used a space between the two (could be optional if you want)

Using Java `Pattern` class to use that regex

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\w+)");
```

Then you just have to iterate on each match to get the couple `type`/`value`

```
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        String type = m.group(2);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))
        ...
    }
```

From that, just use a switch to convert the number into minute and add it to the variable, omitting the `break` to have a nice (but not efficient) converter :

```
switch(type){
//Add more time unit in the correct order if needed
case "days":
    value *= 24;
case "hours":
    value *= 60;
case "mins":
    mins += value;
    break;
}
```

Each type will convert the value into a correct number of minute, at the end, you will have the result in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Problem: There are few concerns as you never know without putting extra conditions like:
15 hours and 15 mins both will be stored in same integer value , you eventually need to differentiate them on some conditions to cater all the issues.

Coming to the question, you may achieve all this by using String split cases but you need to manually cater all the cases keeping in mind a user can use any spell words like **hours** can be **hrs** and so on

Answer (score 2):

You could split the String at the whitespace and use the values in the array.

```
String value1 = "6 hours 43 mins";
String value2 = "15 mins";

String[] resultList1 = value1.split(" ");
String[] resultList2 = value2.split(" ");

int minutes1 = 0;
int minutes2 = 0;

if(resultList1.length == 4) {
  minutes1 = Integer.parseInt(resultList1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(resultList1[2]);
} else {
  minutes1 = Integer.parseInt(resultList1[0]);
}

if(resultList2.length == 4) {
  minutes2 = Integer.parseInt(resultList2[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(resultList2[2]);
} else {
  minutes2 = Integer.parseInt(resultList2[0]);
}

System.out.println(minutes1);
System.out.println(minutes2);
```

The result is:

```
403
15
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can get each minute and hours separately you can use `string.replace("mins", "")` then use `Integer.parseInt()`.
If you get overral like 6 hours 43 mins you must split the string.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this can be done in a single regex, but if I were you I would use a different regex to find the number of hours, the number of minutes, the number of seconds, etc.

Given a string in the format you mentioned, you can first extract the number of hours by using this regex:

```
\d+(?= hours?)
```

Then extract the number of minutes:

```
\d+(?= mins?)
```

If seconds can appear in the input string, you can use this to extract seconds as well:

```
\d+(?= secs?)
```

If any of the regexes don't match, that means there isn't that information in the string.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

```
String time = "6 hours 43 mins";//or (43 mins) or (6 hours)
int h, m;
String[] parts = time.split(" ");
if (parts.length == 4) {
    h = parts[1];
    m = parts[3];
} else if (parts.length == 2) {
    if (parts[1].isEqualTo("hours") {
        h = parts[0];
    } else if (parts[1].isEqualTo("mins") {
        m = parts[0];
    }
}
return h*60+m;
```